# Maxima CAS: How to set domain of function's arguments and parameters?

Tags: functions, constraints, computer-algebra-systems, maxima-software

How can I specify that $a>0$ and $f$ is defined on $(0,1)$ for a toy function $f(x|a)=ax$ in [Maxima CAS](https://maxima.sourceforge.io/)?

```
f(x):=a*x;
```

That is $f:(0,1)\to(0,а)$

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found [`assume()` function](https://maxima.sourceforge.io/docs/manual/maxima_59.html) in Maxima's documentation. It assumes domains (or ranges) of variables. We can also use `facts()` to view current assumptions. For the toy example above, we declare:

```
assume(a>0)$  /% $ sign suppresses the output echo %/
f(x):=a*x$    /% function declaration %/
facts();      /% prints [a>0] %/
```